# Javascript only radio buttons containing children with the same class should appear

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have been locked in this logic for 2 weeks, I need to do that only the "div" containing the "linha-opcao-resposta" class that has other children with the same class.

In other words. 
I need to make the children of the "div" input parent containing "div" children with the same parent class when selected appear and hide the others from the group of radio buttons

Look in the example below.

```html
<div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <label for="7329_2338" title="">27.3 Presença de agentes específicos na citologia oncótica?</label>
    <input type="hidden" title="" id="7329_2338" name="hidden_2338">

  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
    <div style="float:left;">
      <input type="radio" title="" id="7330_2370" name="radio_2370" indicador="CHECKUP_AGEESPCITONC" value="0">
      <label for="7330_2370" title="">Não</label>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
    <div style="float:left;">
      <input type="radio" title="" id="7331_2370" name="radio_2370" indicador="CHECKUP_AGEESPCITONC" value="1">
      <label for="7331_2370" title="">Sim </label>

    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
      <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="7331_2371" title="">27.3.1 Agente 1</label>
        <input type="text" title="" id="7331_2371" name="text_2371" indicador="CHECKUP_AGEESPCITONC_AGENTE_1" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
      <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="7332_2371" title="">27.3.2 Agente 2</label>
        <input type="text" title="" id="7332_2371" name="text_2371" indicador="CHECKUP_AGEESPCITONC_AGENTE_2" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
      <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="7333_2371" title="">27.3.3 Agente 3</label>
        <input type="text" title="" id="7333_2371" name="text_2371" indicador="CHECKUP_AGEESPCITONC_AGENTE_3" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
    <div style="float:left;">
      <input type="radio" title="" id="7334_2370" name="radio_2370" indicador="CHECKUP_AGEESPCITONC" value="2">
      <label for="7334_2370" title="">Exame não realizado</label>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
    <div style="float:left;">
      <input type="radio" title="" id="7405_2370" name="radio_2370" indicador="CHECKUP_AGEESPCITONC" value="3">
      <label for="7405_2370" title="">Não se aplica</label>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

only radio buttons containing children with the same class of "linha-opcao-resposta" should appear, other radio buttons that do not contain, should make those containing children disappear.

I tried to do it this way, but without success.

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var pais = element.parent().parent();
    var filhos;
    var aux = 0;
    pais.forEach(pai => {
        if (element.val() == aux) {
            filhos = pai.children();
            if (filhos.length > 1) {
                for (var j = 0; j < filhos.length; j++) {
                    filhos[j].style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            filhos = pai.children();
            for (var k = 0; k < filhos.length; j++) {
                filhos[k].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        aux++;
    });
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set `display = 'none'` to all radio button's parent. Then set `display = 'block'` only to the radio button's parents matching the condition.  Try the following way:

```js
var radio = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
radio.forEach(function(radEl){
  radEl.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
});

var radShow = document.querySelectorAll('div.linha-opcao-resposta + div.linha-opcao-resposta > div > input[type=radio]');
radShow.forEach(function(radEl){
  radEl.parentElement.style.display = 'block';
});
```

```html
<div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
  <div style="float:left;">
      <label for="7329_2338" title="">27.3 Presença de agentes específicos na citologia oncótica?</label>
      <input type="hidden" title="" id="7329_2338" name="hidden_2338">

  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
      <div style="float:left;">
          <input type="radio" title="" id="7330_2370" name="radio_2370" indicador="CHECKUP_AGEESPCITONC" value="0">
          <label for="7330_2370" title="">Não</label>

      </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
      <div style="float:left;">
          <input type="radio" title="" id="7331_2370" name="radio_2370" indicador="CHECKUP_AGEESPCITONC" value="1">
          <label for="7331_2370" title="">Sim </label>

      </div>
      <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
          <div style="float:left;">
              <label for="7331_2371" title="">27.3.1 Agente 1</label>
              <input type="text" title="" id="7331_2371" name="text_2371" indicador="CHECKUP_AGEESPCITONC_AGENTE_1" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">

          </div>
      </div>
      <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
          <div style="float:left;">
              <label for="7332_2371" title="">27.3.2 Agente 2</label>
              <input type="text" title="" id="7332_2371" name="text_2371" indicador="CHECKUP_AGEESPCITONC_AGENTE_2" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">

          </div>
      </div>
      <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
          <div style="float:left;">
              <label for="7333_2371" title="">27.3.3 Agente 3</label>
              <input type="text" title="" id="7333_2371" name="text_2371" indicador="CHECKUP_AGEESPCITONC_AGENTE_3" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">

          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
      <div style="float:left;">
          <input type="radio" title="" id="7334_2370" name="radio_2370" indicador="CHECKUP_AGEESPCITONC" value="2">
          <label for="7334_2370" title="">Exame não realizado</label>

      </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
      <div style="float:left;">
          <input type="radio" title="" id="7405_2370" name="radio_2370" indicador="CHECKUP_AGEESPCITONC" value="3">
          <label for="7405_2370" title="">Não se aplica</label>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```